# JSON AJax PHP not being able to display data in php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am having some issues being able to see the array variables echoing in PHP, I have tried numerous things, and I know that the array is being sent to the PHP file via JSON and in a stringify version.

I can write the data to a log file and the data that is displayed in the file for the variable: $datastripped is as follows

```
{"supplements":[{"supplement":"1","dose":"2","dosewieght":"mg"}]}
```

the $data variable does not write to the log file no matter how I code it.

I have tried $data, $data[0], $data[0]['supplement'],$data['supplements']['supplement']  and many other combinations.

The information I have found on JSON and that has worked for others does not appear to work for me.

*** I am doing this inside WordPress as well, but have verified that the data is correctly getting to the php function, but can not echo individual items out

Here is the Javascript:

```
var supplist = {supplements:[]};
supplist.supplements.push({supplement:supplement, dose:dose, dosewieght:doseweight});

$( "#supplementsave" ).click(function(){
    var jsonsupparray = JSON.stringify(supplist); 


        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                url: myajax.ajax_url,
                data:{

                        data:jsonsupparray,
                        action: "addsupplements"            
                },
                cache:false,
                success: function(data){
                console.log("success");
                },

    });
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$datastripped =stripslashes($_POST['data']);

$data = json_decode($datastripped, true);   //Data Not Beign shown

foreach($data as $value){

echo $value['supplement'];

}
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using `.stringify()`? Comment out that line and comment out the lines with `stripslashes()` and `json_decode()`. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just it

```
<?php
    $datastripped = '{"supplements":[{"supplement":"1","dose":"2","dosewieght":"mg"}]}';
    $data = json_decode($datastripped, true);
    // print_r($data['supplements']);
    foreach ($data['supplements'][0] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

You will get

```
supplement 1
dose 2
dosewieght mg
```

If you want call one parameter

```
echo $data['supplements'][0]['supplement'];
echo $data['supplements'][0]['dose'];
echo $data['supplements'][0]['dosewieght'];
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to put single quotes, when you push data in your supplist.

```
supplist.supplements.push({'supplement':'supplement', 'dose':'dose', 'dosewieght':'doseweight'});
```

Otherwise it throws javascript error that supplement is not defined, because it treats supplement as variable, not as a string.

Now in your php code You need to decode and your json and iterate.